# What can a "Device Owner" app do?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, permissions, 7.1-nougat

I've been searching around to find an answer to what "permissions" a device owner app on 7.0< has, but I can't find a clear answer?

Can anybody hear help me out, or maybe point me in the right direction?

I don't know much about coding.. :/

Comment: do you mean system app/pre-installed app as device owner app?

Comment: No :) If I install an app and set it as Device Owner (via ADB) what will it be able to do? :O

Sorry, should have been more specific.

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/181006/96277?

Comment: Yes I am :) But my question is actually related to that one (also by me). 
Basically I'm asking because I really like the funcionallity of Ice Box, but I also realise I might be putting myself at risk giving the app Device Owner permissions. So I just want to know how bad it could potentionally harm me if it wanted to...